# When convert syntax to swift 3, Type 'Any' has no subscript members?

Tags: json, swift3

the error "Type 'Any' has no subscript members." in line return at $0["deadline"].

this only happened when I converted syntax to swift 3.

TodoList file

```
fileprivate let ITEMS_KEY = "todoItems"

func allItems() -> [TodoItem] {
    let todoDictionary = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: ITEMS_KEY) ?? [:]
    let items = Array(todoDictionary.values)
    return items.map({TodoItem(deadline: $0["deadline"] as Date, title: $0["title"] as! String, UUID: $0["UUID"] as! String!)}).sort({(left: TodoItem, right:TodoItem) -> Bool in
        (left.deadline.compare(right.deadline) == .orderedAscending)
    })
}
```

TodoItem file

```
struct TodoItem {
var title: String
var deadline: Date
var UUID: String

init(deadline: Date, title: String, UUID: String) {
    self.deadline = deadline
    self.title = title
    self.UUID = UUID
}

var isOverdue: Bool {
    return (Date().compare(self.deadline) == ComparisonResult.orderedDescending)

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you cannot access a value of a struct using the subscript syntax, you have to use dot syntax, like this: `let deadline = todoItem.deadline`, where `todoItem` is an instance of the `TodoItem` class.

Secondly, you have to cast the retrieved dictionary from `UserDefaults` to `[String:TodoItem]`, since `UserDefaults.dictionary(forKey:)` returns a dictionary of type `[String:Any]`.

See the working code below:

```
func allItems() -> [TodoItem] {
    let todoDictionary = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: ITEMS_KEY) as? [String:TodoItem] ?? [:]
    let items = Array(todoDictionary.values)
    return items.map({TodoItem(deadline: $0.deadline, title: $0.title, UUID: $0.UUID)}).sort({(left: TodoItem, right:TodoItem) -> Bool in
        (left.deadline.compare(right.deadline) == .orderedAscending)
    })
}
```